# Creating electronic parts from scratch

Tags: components, schematics, books

So I want to create my own electronic parts from scratch,I don't like buying stuff from internet because it's mostly expensive and I believe if you make it yourself its more cheaper. You might ask what I mean by electronic parts. The simple ones like Ultrasonic sensor,Servo motor and other type of sensors.
Yeah I know there is factories out there making that stuff and making one by hand is hard and sometimes impossible due to small size.So my question: where do I find book,pdf or something that tells me how to make them?

If there is no answer to what I ask above then I highly need schematics for that kind of things(ultrasonic sensor for example).Very detailed and serious,not basic things that show only visible areas.
I believe its written in academic books and are taught in universities but right now I don't study in good university so I don't have that kind of books.I mean if there is factories out there building that small electronic parts there have to be any FULL manual,schematics or design for that things.
Where I can get that schematics or specific books that show how they work,designed,which materials,sizes of specific areas etc?

In the end my question is very easy,that factories have some information on how to make some exact parts(like ultrasonic sensor),where do I get that information too?

Comment: Good luck.  To get anything like the quality and reliability of purchased parts, you are going to need a garage full of special tools, materials, and chemicals.  An ultrasonic sensor, for example, will need a particular type of crystal with electrical contacts bonded to it such that the current generated in the crystal actually flows through the wires.  The information is certainly to be found, but it will be difficult to get it all together and learn the manufacturing techniques needed.

Comment: Thanks,yeah I know and said sometimes building it is impossible,but at least I want to know what is inside it,what material,size,etc,etc in here.Like for example you told me about crystal.How did you get that information?Where I can learn too

Comment: I'd start with the oldest books you can find on the subject, and look for academic papers on the same subject.  Lots of old stuff can be found for free on the internet.  Old stuff, because it will be more in line with what you can do in a home workshop and because modern techniques are proprietarty and generally require a factory full of people to make use of.

Comment: Here's someone making a field effect transistor: http://hackaday.com/2010/05/13/transistor-fabrication-so-simple-a-child-can-do-it/

Comment: I think much of this stuff is a trade secret or that requires PHD worthy levels of expertise. Let's consider a "schematic" for even a simple ceramic chip resistor. We know it is made of some ceramic but what exact material? How would I achieve an XR7 rating? How are the metal contacts bonded? These are secrets you'd have to learn by either working for companies like Panasonic or by following conferences and academic research. In all likelihood, companies like Panasonic work with academia to answer these questions. This level of detail would not be found in an undergraduate text book.

Comment: thanks again that was useful,any particular book or site to look for that books?Right now I even don't know what to do to find that kind of books,literally no any idea

Comment: Why are you so sure you can make something cheaper than you can buy it, if you have no clue how to make it?

Comment: @Huseyn26 I think your problem is that you want **specific** information on a certain subject yet you neglect the "bigger picture". For example: you want to make your own resistor but fail to understand what a resistor is and what it does, what it's limitations are. Maybe you already know this but to me it seems like you don't.

Comment: @MattYoung that was half of my question that I want to make it,in the second one I said if thats not possible(making) then at least I want to know how to make one(not making one,knowing how to make one)

Comment: @FakeMoustache yeah I don't know about it and I want to learn,that was my question from start to know how it works,designed and etc.Forget about making it part,it doesn't matter if I make it,at least I want to know how to make it

Comment: The parts are cheap for the factories because they build machines to make the parts then make and sell parts by the millions.

Comment: Then why don't you start at the beginning. Read a beginners book about electronics and take it from there. I for example started with a Philips electronics kit when I was a kid. Then I read more. Then I studied electronics. It takes years. Electronics is a broad field, I am sure there are much more interesting and more accessible subjects than making your own components. Sure, Edison and Tesla made their own components ! Why ? Because they could not buy any on ebay !

Comment: I suggest you start with something simple.  Make a simple carbon resistor - like this http://www.troelsgravesen.dk/graphite.htm  See what you are up against?

Comment: Thanks,that was useful,and @JRE how do you find these?

Comment: Here's another good one... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CplJjvbCaX4

Comment: I find them by searching for the terms involved.  I know (and you can easily find out) that a resistor can be made from carbon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor#Carbon_composition )  I also know that graphite is a form of carbon that is readily available (pencil lead) so I searched for pencil lead resistors.

Comment: http://www.sparkbangbuzz.com/

Answer (score 3):

*"it's mostly expensive and I believe if you make it yourself its more cheaper."*

Then by all means go ahead and do so.

I think you have a very strong and very wrong opinion about these matters.

I think you have been looking in the wrong places. If you want cheap electronics parts, shop on ebay.

*"there have to be any FULL manual,schematics or design for that things"*

Wrong again, have you never heard of the term "company secret" or "patents". If you design something clever you do not want everyone to be able to just copy it and sell it. You want everyone to come to you to buy it ! There are of course some open source parts but most of these are not intended for commercial purposes and/or mass production.

Comment: what about parts that have been in earth from like 1900s?Like companies that build that parts don't exists anymore?

and you know there is many factories,how come they all have very similar products?So they all know the technique ,how one new company learns when other is keeping that secret?
Ok may be I am wrong in my second paragraph,but what about old 1900s electronic parts?

Comment: What 1900s electronic parts ? Please give an example.

Comment: If you still want to buy cheaper,then try Alibaba,aliexpress.They are very cheap when compared to e-bay.But not gurantee for original.

Comment: Yeah to be real actually I don't know any example,may be that is my mistake but as you said earlier I have strong belief that it can be done,ok for example some simple part in old cameras that worked with tapes

Comment: *"I have strong belief that it can be done"* In engineering, "believing" is usually **irrelevant**, in engineerign we want **proof**. So prove your statement. My counter-proof is that in the old days components were much-much more expensive than they are now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make something fairly simple, it's easy enough - I was seriously contemplating making some low-ohm power resistors from strands of steel picture hanging wire when I discovered that I'd ordered the right value, been invoiced for the right value, and something a factor of 11 different had been shipped (and then sat too long to be returned without my having noticed that they were not what they were supposed to be.) After some basic testing of my bootleg resistor approach I ordered some from eBay - I could make it work if I had to, but it's not time efficient, and that's not money efficient...

The tales of the many odd things that will work (or work somewhat) as a diode is pretty common in "crystal radio" literature. I have my doubts about using most of those for rectifying a power supply. Various things make crude capacitors fairly easily - aluminum foil and waxed paper, for one example. Even those get hard if you are locating and mining the bauxite to produce the aluminum and then rolling it into foil yourself, and cutting the trees to make the paper, and drilling oil wells for the petroleum-based wax. Especially if you also have to find and mine the iron ore and smelt it to make the iron and steel for the machinery.

If you'd like to make crystals (either for piezo discs as used in ultrasonic sensors or for timing crystals), you can buy some high quality quartz, or shovel some sand into your handy quartz-crystal-growing-oven, cut it at precise angles with your diamond saw, pop it in your vacuum-metalization chamber to plate some contacts on it. This will not be cheaper than buying a crystal/piezo/etc. until you are at a scale of millions of parts, assuming you can actually develop the skill to produce useful parts at all.

Following the suggestions to look at old stuff, if you are willing to invest a certain amount you could potentially make vacuum tubes (assuming you were willing to buy some stuff) for only a few orders of magnitude more than you can buy them, and you'd hit "cheaper than buying them" at a much lower production volume - if you did a good job you might even be able to sell them and make a profit (some folks still like them for certain applications.)